# Fastest way to index an element in a sorted list in python?

Tags: python, search, time, indexing

Python's lists have a function `list.index(elem)` which, to the best of my knowledge, run in O(n) time. However, if I can guarantee the list to be sorted, is this still the best way to get the index of an element?

Will a binary search return the index faster? Also, is there a way to force the python Standard library to do a binary search for the index of an element in a list?

Comment: This seems like a question for [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and is not related to Ubuntu.

Comment: Terribly sorry.. Wrong stack... The app is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a binary search will generally be faster. No, the standard library `index` function has no option for that.

[Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2233940) has code for a binary search:

```python
from bisect import bisect_left

def binary_search(a, x, lo=0, hi=None):   # can't use a to specify default for hi
    hi = hi if hi is not None else len(a) # hi defaults to len(a)   
    pos = bisect_left(a,x,lo,hi)          # find insertion position
    return (pos if pos != hi and a[pos] == x else -1) # don't walk off the end
```

Comment: What happens in the case of duplicate elements in the list?

Comment: Like the `index` function, it returns the first index it sees, which, unlike `index`, may be anywhere within a bunch of matches. Since the list is sorted, you can go backward linearly until you find a nonmatching element to find where the first match is and then forward to find the last match. You can also use binary search with `lo` and `hi` set appropriately to search before what it found last time until it can't find anything, and then do the same sort of thing to find the last occurrence.